# Linking ZBar library in CMakeFile

Tags: c++, camera, cmake, raspberry-pi, zbar

I want to scan QR code live with Raspberry Pi and its cam module. I am going use zbar, opencv with C++. I already installed zbar, opencv and testing of camera is working. I don't know how to link to zbar library in CMakeLists.txt . In general, I don't know how to link a library in CMake. The following text is from CMakeList.txt.

```
find_package(raspicam REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV)
IF  ( OpenCV_FOUND AND raspicam_CV_FOUND)
MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILING OPENCV TESTS")
add_executable (main  main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main ${raspicam_CV_LIBS}${ZBAR_LIBRARIES}zbar)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} /usr/local/lib/cmake/)
ELSE()
MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "OPENCV NOT FOUND IN YOUR SYSTEM")
ENDIF()
```

I am having error

```
Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lraspicam_cvzbar
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please tell me how to link zbar library in Raspberry PI or how to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is probably in `target_link_libraries (main ${raspicam_CV_LIBS}${ZBAR_LIBRARIES}zbar)` What is in those variables?

Comment: The error is clear: you are not giving the correct path of the libraries to the linker

Comment: add a space between the libs: `target_link_libraries (main ${raspicam_CV_LIBS} ${ZBAR_LIBRARIES} zbar)`

Comment: Thanks @berak . It's working now. It needs a space in between. Al least, I can compile online examples for now. I need to learn how to link a library in CMake. Those CMake online tutorial are complicated.